# codeigniter upload->do_upload() with $_FILES instead of field name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

is it possible to make a upload with the $_FILE var using the upload library from CodeIgniter?

```
 $this->upload->do_upload('field_name')
```

It requires the html field name as a parameters. But I need to make a upload with de $_FILES.

The problem is:
I must be able to add more photos to a form before submitting it. I used a (+) button to clone the fields. Like this:

**HTML:**

```
...

<span onclick='duplicarCampos()'> + </span>

<div class="form-group">

    <div id="destino" class="col-lg-12">

        <div id="fabricas" class="col-lg-4 fabricas">

            <label>Imagem:</label>
            <input name="img[]" type="file" class="form-control">

            <label>Link:</label>
            <input name="link[]" type="text" class="form-control">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

I'm submitting the form with AJAX, like this:

**JS TO SUBMIT:**

```
...

var imagens = $("input[name='img[]']").map(function () {
    return   $(this).prop("files")[0];
}).get();

var links = $("input[name='link[]']").map(function () {
    return   $(this).val();
}).get();

var form_data = new FormData();

for(i=0; i<imagens.length; i++){
    form_data.append("imagens_"+i,imagens[i]);
    form_data.append("links_"+i,links[i]);
}
form_data.append("lastIndice",(i-1));

$.ajax({
    ...
});

...
```

In my **PHP Controller** I receive them like this:

```
...    

for($i=0; $i < $lastIndice+1; $i++){
    $links[$i] = $_POST["links_".$i];
}

for($j=0; $j < $lastIndice+1; $j++){
    $imagens[$j] = $_FILES["imagens_".$j];
}

...
```

Now, I wanna upload each image with the **upload library from CodeIgniter**. But the only way I know it works is using the **html field name**, not the **$_FILES** as a parameter of do_upload()...

**USING UPLOAD LIBRARY:**

```
...

if(!$ci->upload->do_upload($this->nome_campo)) {
    ...
}

...
```

I could make the upload "normally" with PHP, but I'm new at the CodeIgniter and I want to learn how to do things with it.

Comment: Multiple select should not be `<input name="img[]" type="file"`. Its `<input name="img" type="file" multiple`

Comment: @DeadManAlive hello, I can’t do that. Because I also need to set a link for each image. The user needs to upload an image and a link to redirect when the image is clicked.

Comment: Its doesnt matter what you do. Its how you upload multiple files properly. once you got all the files you can do any in back-end

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your current iteration:

```
for($j=0; $j < $lastIndice+1; $j++){
    $imagens[$j] = $_FILES["imagens_".$j];
}
```

It looks like your `$_FILES` array is structured in this manner (example):

```
(
    [imagens_0] => Array
        (
            [name] => foo.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 123
        )

    [imagens_1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bar.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 456
        )
)
```

Codeigniter's `do_upload()` expects the key value of the $_FILES array holding your file info. Therefore by changing your `for` loop in this manner, you should be able to upload it:

```
for($j=0; $j < $lastIndice+1; $j++){
    $this->upload->do_upload("imagens_".$j);
}
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank’s!